# Runnable's run method runs faster in android

Tags: performance, handler

I have two fragment. in first I am showing timer. And it works fine until I stay on this first fragment. but when I replace this first fragment with second fragment and again come back on this first fragment then, run method of Runnable runs faster than specified time. this my code below

```
private fun runTimer() {
    // Creates a new Handler
    val handler = Handler()
    thread{
        handler.post(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val h = seconds / 3600
                val m = (seconds % 3600) / 60
                val s = (seconds % 60)
                binding.timeTv.text = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)

                if (running) {
                    seconds++
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)

            }
        })
    }

}
```

please help how can I run timer on a one second even after changing fragment and again come back on previous one.